# Java Regex - find a numeric value in a String

Tags: java, regex

In the below two strings (weather mesures) I need to find with a regex expression the first `"xxxFT"` value after `"BKN"` then extract only numerical value : `xxxx`

In the 1st String final value will be `2400` and `700` in the second.

Between `"BKN"` and `"xxxxFT"` ther could be an additionnal word or not, it depends. ie : `"BKN CB 2400FT"` or `"BKN 700FT"`

```
String str1 = "4000M WX MODTSRA CLD FEW 600FT BKN CB 2400FT BKN CB 2900FT T 21 DP 18 QNH 1010.7HPA MET QFE 1004.1HPA TREND TEMPO MOD TSRA"

String str2 = "1500M CLD BKN 700FT BKN 4600FT T 16 DP 17 QNH 1014.7HPA MET QFE 1004.1HPA TREND TEMPO MOD TSRA"
```

Which regex pattern could I use for this ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you need all the values with xxxFT as a pattern ?

Comment: BKN.*?\s+(\d+)FT will work in both of the cases you've provided - it actually grabs all of the xxx's, but you can just take the first one. BTW, for regex, you can go to regex101.com, which is a fantastic resource for regex. (I'm not affiliated.)

Comment: @Jeutnarg thank you very much it works fine !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a reference to Jeutnarg comment, we can have a solution without any substring or etc. by using Matcher groups:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

    String text    =
        "4000M WX MODTSRA CLD FEW 600FT BKN CB 2400FT BKN CB 2900FT T" + 
        " 21 DP 18 QNH 1010.7HPA MET QFE 1004.1HPA TREND TEMPO MOD TSRA";
        text = "1500M CLD BKN 700FT BKN 4600FT T 16 DP 17 QNH 1014.7HPA MET QFE 1004.1HPA TREND TEMPO MOD TSRA";

    String patternString = "BKN.*?\\s+(\\d+)FT";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing matched");
    }
}
```

output would be what is asked. 2400 and 700 for the first and second string accordingly.

If there is multiple matches is the input string then the only thing needs to be changed is the if statement which should be converted to while.

```
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: is that useful to you?

Comment: Yes it works very well and I raised my comprehension of regex :o)

Comment: That's a good news. Then you can select the right answer to help other users with the same question to find their response sooner. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
If you want with a single regex use following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("BKN.*?\\s+(\\d+)FT");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String1);
if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Old** Firstly you need to get the SubString starting from BKN so

```
int startIndex = String1.indexOf("BKN");
String str = String1.subString(startIndex);
```

Then You need to cut it down between BKN and FT so in order to do that get the index of FT

```
startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = str.indexOf("FT")+1;
str = str.subString(startIndex,endIndex);
```

And then finally You can use this regex and delete non-digit characters from the string

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Output of String1 : 2400
Output of String2: 700

Comment: It's what I did but thought there was a better possibility to find it with only one magical regex. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with a single regex please check